# Firefox (36?) don't select twice an option changing the "select" attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

First the example here

http://jsfiddle.net/93m1agha/

```
$opt = $("option").not(":first");
console.log($opt);    


$button = $(".control div");

$button.click(function(ev){
    var id = $(ev.target).index();
    $opt.removeAttr("selected");
    $opt.eq(id).attr("selected", "selected");
})
```

With Chrome
If you click one of the A/B/C box, the select above will change the selected option according your action. You can click as you want and everything work perfectly.

With FF36 
If you click the same button twice it seems the browser can't reselect the correct option.

FF Bug? My error? Any suggestion?
Thx

Comment: Try `$opt.eq(id).prop("selected", true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selected attribute is mainly used to set the initial value, at runtime it is safe to set the selected property value

```
$button.click(function(ev){
    var id = $(ev.target).index();
    $opt.eq(id).prop("selected", true);
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q12da625/)